# Using a macro generated variable within Evaluate function

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a macro variable active_search, which I'm trying to include in an evaluate function. However, the evaluate function is not outputting the correct value. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Code:

```
' this accurately provides the cell reference for the formula below
active_search = Cells(i, search_col).Address
active_match = Cells(i, match_col).Address

MsgBox active_search    ' = &B$3 (or row i)
MsgBox active_match     ' = $A$3


' formulas for the criteria below
' check_search = [IFERROR(MATCH(B3,list_keywords,0),0)]    << Note: this works correctly
check_search = [IFERROR(MATCH(active_search,list_keywords,0),0)]
check_match = [IFERROR(SEARCH("exact",active_match,0)]

MsgBox check_search     ' currently = 0 but should be 2250
MsgBox check_match
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `check_match = Evaluate("IFERROR(SEARCH(""exact""," & active_match & ",0)")`

Answer (score 0):

Let us expound what @simoco commented.

`[]` which is a shortcut for `Evaluate` function doesn't work on `Variables`.
To make it work, you have to explicitly use it as what simoco does in his comment.
To get the correct values use these instead (one already provided by simoco)

```
check_search = Evaluate("IFERROR(MATCH(" & active_search & "list_keywords,0),0)")
'~~> provided that list_keywords is named Range
check_match = Evaluate("IFERROR(SEARCH(""exact""," & active_match & ",0),0)")
```

**Syntax:** *Evaluate*(**name**) wherein the `name` argument is in a form of string.